# How can we get data from multiple data base in django orm?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to get data from multiple databases in Django ORM

> Select  em.EMPLOYEEID_N, tran.TRANSFERID_N,dep.HRDEPT_ID_V as
>   HRDEPT_ID_V, dep.ACCOUNTSDEPT_ID_V as ACCOUNTSDEPT_ID_V,
>   dep.ADMINDEPT_ID_V as ADMINDEPT_ID_V, dep.ITDEPT_ID_V as
>   ITDEPT_ID_V,NVL(chk.HR_DPT,'N') HR_DPT, NVL(chk.ACCOUNTS_DPT,'N')
>   ACCOUNTS_DPT , NVL(chk.ADMIN_DPT,'N') ADMIN_DPT , NVL(chk.IT_DPT,'N')
>   IT_DPT, dep.RECIEVINGACCOUNTSDEPT_ID_V,
>   NVL(dep.RECIEVINGACCOUNTSCHECK,'N') RECACCOUNTS_DPT, hr.UNITID_N
>   USRUNITID,DEP.UNITID_N TFRUNITID    From  PYR_EMM_EMPLOYEEMASTER
>   em,PYR_EMM_TRANSFERINOUTSTATUS tran,PYR_EMM_TRANSFERADV_CHECKLIST
>   chk,PYR_EMM_TA_DEPTALERT dep, PYR_EMM_EMPLOYEEMASTER hr Where 
>   em.EMPLOYEEID_N = tran.EMPLOYEEID_N and tran.TRANSFERID_N =
>   chk.TRANSFERID_N and tran.EMPLOYEEID_N = chk.EMPLOYEEID_N and
>   tran.TRANSFERID_N = dep.TRANSFERID_N and tran.EMPLOYEEID_N =
>   dep.EMPLOYEEID_N and hr.ACTDIRUSERNAME_V = 'ithd.ggn'  and
>   chk.UNITID_N = dep.UNITID_N and (dep.HRDEPT_ID_V =
>   'ithd.ggn'||'@bilt.com' or dep.ACCOUNTSDEPT_ID_V =
>   'ithd.ggn'||'@bilt.com' or dep.ADMINDEPT_ID_V =
>   'ithd.ggn'||'@bilt.com' or dep.ITDEPT_ID_V = 'ithd.ggn'||'@bilt.com'
>   or dep.RECIEVINGACCOUNTSDEPT_ID_V = 'ithd.ggn'||'@bilt.com')

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/), implement it, and ask a question if you face any specific issue. As it stands now, you haven't told us about any problem you're facing, so this question should be closed.

Comment: Thankyou dirkgroten actually I'm confused in multi database-related query